# Clear a Picturebox.backgroundimage in c#

Tags: c#, background-image, picturebox

I have a picturebox where i can load a image into its .backgroundimage function and now i have a button that is suppose to clear it but doesn't. I have tried using this code:
secondcapturebox.Dispose();
But yet still the image is in the picturebox.
Please Help,

Thanks

Comment: You picked the wrong answer.  Don't bypass Dispose() just because it didn't work when you tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
secondcapturebox.BackgroundImage = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set it to null.  Like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (pictureBox1.BackgroundImage != null) {
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pictureBox1.Image = null;
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
pictureBox1.BringToFront();

pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = null;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer could benefit from a little explanation _why_ and _how_ this code solves the question.